# WHM backup and transfer

Tags: backup, cpanel, transfer, whm

I have a web site on the cpanel(whm), I want to backup whole site and transfer it to another stand-alone server of my own, is that feasible? how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If the new server doesn't have cPanel I don't think there is a method of recreating automatically the account, so just try to run /scripts/pkgacct user(if you have root on cPanel server) or just use cPanel -> Backups -> Download or generate a full website backup.

Copy archive to the new server and start to manually recreate account, databases, etc.

Archive contain all the informations you need like dnszones, mysql databases, homedir.tar(all the files from /home/user), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! its easy!

1. Login to WHM
2. On the left there is Search box type Backup and click on Backup Configuration (OR go to Backup >> Backup Configuration)
3. Change Backup Status to enable
4. Check the options as per your requirement & at the end of page find Additional Destinations there might be drop down OR check box for FTP server click on that
5. FTP details of another server where you want to store all of your backups.

Hope it helps!